# What kind of plot am I looking at?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, data-visualization

I stumbled on to these following two slides (slides 21 & 22 on a machine learning tutorial found [here](http://alex.smola.org/teaching/pune2007/pune_5.pdf)):

[image: Scatterplot..]
[image]

The first is obviously an $x,y$ scatterplot of height and weight.

**But what is the second?**  Looks like two component parts representing the original data, but I can really tease out what is going on. Any insight (or reproducible R code, or even Pseudo-code) on what the heat map is representing, and what the white lines are interpreted as would be great.

Comment: A guess: The heatmap corresponds to the ellipsoidal contours of a multivariate Gaussian density obtained by fitting the data (probably by maximum likelihood or similar). The white contour lines correspond to the conditional (Gaussian) density obtained from conditioning on the given height, so, e.g., the bottom line is the density for weights given a height of 140 (cm, I'd guess). Do you have access to the underlying data?

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have the scatterplot visually.. I think I can see the conditional distributions in the white lines and the max likelihood seems a good guess at the heat map.  thanks

Comment: If the slides were done by the person who is named at the bottom of the slides, why not ask [him](http://alex.smola.org/) what they are? It's likely to be more accurate than the out-of-context guesses - however plausible they may be - that we could make.

Comment: The white horizontal lines are identical - just shifted to the right as a function of vertical position.  I suspect they traverse the semi-major axis of the principal ellipsoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A guess: The heatmap corresponds to the ellipsoidal contours of a multivariate Gaussian density obtained by fitting the data (probably by maximum likelihood or similar). The white contour lines correspond to the conditional (Gaussian) density obtained from conditioning on the given height, so, e.g., the bottom line is the density for weights given a height of 140 (cm, I'd guess).

-cardinal

> If the slides were done by the person who is named at the bottom of the slides, why not ask him what they are? It's likely to be more accurate than the out-of-context guesses - however plausible they may be - that we could make.

-Glen_b

Comment: I've copied these comments as a community wiki answer because they are, more or less, answers to this question. We have a dramatic gap between answers and questions. At least part of the problem is that some questions are answered in comments: if comments which answered the question were answers instead, we would have fewer unanswered questions.